# A value sended by host not return correctly by device using CUDA Fortran

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, fortran, gpgpu, pgi

I took an example of data transfer between Host and Device for CUDA Fortran and found this:

Host Code:

```
program incTest  
    use cudafor
    use simpleOps_m
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n = 256
    integer :: a(n), b, i
    integer, device :: a_d(n)
    a = 1
    b = 3
    a_d = a
    call inc<<<1,n>>>(a_d, b)
    a = a_d
    if (all(a == 4)) then
        write(*,*) 'Success'
    endif
end program incTest
```

Device Code:

```
module simpleOps_m
contains
    attributes(global) subroutine inc(a, b)
        implicit none
        integer :: a(:)
        integer, value :: b
        integer :: i
        i = threadIdx%x
        a(i) = a(i)+b
    end subroutine inc
end module simpleOps_m
```

The expected outcome is the console presenting "Success", but this did not happen. Nothing appears in the screen, nothing errors or messages. 
This happen because don't enter in if, because a_d has the same value that before call inc subroutine.

I'm using:

OS: Linux - Ubuntu 16

Cuda 8

PGI to compile

Commands to compile:

```
pgf90 -Mcuda -c Device.cuf
pgf90 -Mcuda -c Host.cuf
pgf90 -Mcuda -o HostDevice Device.o Host.o
./HostDevice
```

I tried other examples and they did not work too.

I tried using simple Fortran (.f90) code with the same commands to compile and it works!

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: *"Has anyone ever had this problem?"* Such a poll is off-topic here. A question how to avoid or fix the problem is on-topic.

Comment: *"The expected outcome is the console presenting "Success", but this did not happen"* So what exactly happened? Any error message? Which one? Wrong results? How did they look like? Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and tips, Vladimir F.
Nothing appears in the screen, nothing errors or messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of device are you using? (If you don't know, post the output from the "pgaccelinfo" utility).

My best guess is that you have a Pascal based device in which case you need to compile with "-Mcuda=cc60".

For example, if I add error checking to the example code, we see that we get an invalid device kernel error when running on a Pascal without the "cc60" as part of the compilation.

```
% cat test.cuf 
 module simpleOps_m 
      contains 
          attributes(global) subroutine inc(a, b) 
              implicit none 
              integer :: a(:) 
              integer, value :: b 
              integer :: i 
              i = threadIdx%x 
              a(i) = a(i)+b 
          end subroutine inc 
  end module simpleOps_m 

 program incTest 
          use cudafor 
          use simpleOps_m 
          implicit none 
          integer, parameter :: n = 256 
          integer :: a(n), b, i, istat 
          integer, device :: a_d(n) 
          a = 1 
          b = 3 
          a_d = a 
          call inc<<<1,n>>>(a_d, b) 
          istat=cudaDeviceSynchronize() 
          istat=cudaGetLastError() 
          a = a_d 
          if (all(a == 4)) then 
              write(*,*) 'Success' 
          else 
              write(*,*) 'Error code:', cudaGetErrorString(istat) 
          endif 
  end program incTest 
 % pgf90 test.cuf -Mcuda 
 % a.out 
  Error code: 
  invalid device function                                                        
 % pgf90 test.cuf -Mcuda=cc60 
 % a.out 
  Success
```

Comment: CUDA Driver Version:           8000
NVRM version:                  NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.39  
Device Number:                 0
Device Name:                   GeForce GTX 1080
PGI Compiler Option:           -ta=tesla:cc60; This are the informations by pgaccelinfo. I compiled with -Mcuda=cc60 and did right! Thank you Mat Colgrove!